# Splitting Handlebars template path between lines

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, eslint

I am working on an EmberJS app, and in the tests I have got multiple occurrences of:

```
this.render(hbs`{{directory1/directory2/directory3/directory4/directory5/directory6/directory1/directory8/ hasMyAction=(action hasMyAction)}}`);
```

I have got an ESLint max line length of 120. How can I split the line of code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// eslint-disable-next-line
this.render(hbs`{{directory1/directory2/directory3/directory4/directory5/directory6/directory1/directory8/
  hasMyAction=(action hasMyAction)
}}`);
```

Can't break up the path, as far as I know, but you can tell ESLint to ignore the line.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this:

```
const context = [
  'directory1',
  'directory2',
  'directory3',
  'directory4',
  'directory5',
  'directory6',
  'directory7'
].join('/');

const componentPath = `${context}/component-name`;

this.render(hbs`{{${componentPath} hasMyAction=(action hasMyAction)}}`);
```

though, personally, I'm not sure if backtick templates do interpolation that way, so maybe this could be an alternative:

```
this.set('componentPath', componentPath);

this.render(hbs`{{component componentPath hasMyAction=(action hasMyAction)}}`
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your reply. As far as the first solution, I get a Build Error (broccoli-persistent-filter:Babel > [Babel: oam])

.../component-test.js: placeholders inside a tagged template string are not supported

Comment: Ah, that's probably me not knowing template strings in JavaScript. Does the second way work?

Comment: Unfortunately no... I get the following error: Error: Compile Error: componentPath is not a helper

Comment: what kind of test is this? cause that should work.
and componentPath should be recognized as a variable in `{{component componentPath}}`

Comment: can you add some updated code that you've tried to your post?